# Newly created user on Ubuntu Server has the wrong shell prompt

Tags: shell, users, useradd

I've created a new user in the Ubuntu 18.04.01 like this:

```
sudo useradd svn
sudo passwd svn
sudo mkhomedir_helper svn
sudo usermod -d /home/svn -m svn
```

Problem is, that if I switch to the user by `su svn` I don't see a standard prompt command. Instead of standard prompt:

```
svn@svn-server:/srv/svn/$
```

I see only:

```
$
```

despite the content of the file `/home/svn/.bashrc`. And in this "crippled" prompt I also cannot use TAB key to autocomplete paths.

If I run `echo $PS1` as `svn` user I get empty result.

How can I fix this user?

Comment: Any particular reason you use `useradd` and not `adduser`? I usually use `adduser username` or `adduser --encrypt-home username` when creating a new user.

Comment: @kasperd `adduser` is also typically configured to give a user `bash` instead of `sh` :)

Comment: @kasperd the reason is simple. I didn't know the command `adduser`. So, thx. I'll use it in the future.

Comment: That _is_ the standard prompt.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check the shell you have assigned. If you used the `useradd` command in Ubuntu 18, the default login shell will be `/bin/sh` and you will get output like you mentioned. You can change the login shell by executing the command:

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash svn
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want ALL new users to use the same shell, you can set that using `/etc/default/useradd`.  Change the `SHELL` setting to reflect the path to the shell binary you want to use.  For example, mine looks like:

```
HOME=/home
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes
```

Also worth noting, you can use the directory named in your `SKEL` setting to define what files should be copied into a new user's home directory by default.  In my case, I have a `.zshrc` file containing zsh configurations I want for all new users.

Use these two files to set defaults for all new users.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shell as the new user:

```
$ chsh
Changing shell for svn.
New shell [/bin/sh]: /bin/bash
Password: ****
Shell changed.
```

There may be other mop-up work to do, such as if the account is missing parts of the expected "skeleton" content.  You mention `~/.bashrc`, so maybe that's not a problem here.